# How to connect google font to page?

Tags: css, html, fonts, google-webfonts

I have used recommendations in Google Fonts how to set fonts. So I did the following actions:

1) Added this ependency on the page:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet">
```

2) Set CSS to body tag:

```
 html, body {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        background: #f7f7f7;
    }
```

When I tried to set font for another elements like:

```
a {
font-family: Roboto-Light;
}
```

It does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a {
   font-family: 'Roboto'; /* You don't need this since you say html {font-family: 'Roboto'}*/
   font-weight: 100;
}
/*Font's family name need to be inside quotes "MyFontName"
```

Answer (score 1):

`Roboto` and `Roboto-Light` are two different font faces from the website's point of view. When you use `Roboto-Light` it doesn't know you want the thin font-weight from `Roboto`. It just looks for any font-face named `Roboto-Light`, which you did not load, define or declare.

You probably want to use something like:

```
a {
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

It will use the `Roboto` font-face, because it's already set on any element, by setting it on `body`, but will now use the `100` font-weight, which is really, really thin.

Comment: Look attachment, this is not Roboto

Comment: That's probably because you have a stronger rule applying on those elements. `a` is just element selector, really weak. It's overridden by any `.class` selector or `#id` selector. Just inspect the element and see what applies and where it comes from. You'll need to make your selector stronger than that. Why don't you provide a [mcve]? I can't inspect a picture, can I?

Answer (score 1):

**To embed any Google Font into a webpage do the following (Roboto Light example):**

1. Open [Google Fonts](https://developers.google.com/fonts/) site, click on "See Available Fonts" and then select the [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) font.
2. Click on "Select This Font" (red link above).
3. Click on "1 Family Selected" snackbar below and then click on "Customize" tab.
4. Select the Light style. Note that the weight 300 is displayed.
5. Select the "Embed" tab and you will have the link tag for the [Roboto Light](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?selection.family=Roboto:300) font.

**See the HTML example below:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-size: 48px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Making the Web Beautiful!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```